# Increment not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple app in which I want music that is uploaded to have a 'like' functionality where it keeps track of the number of likes.

Musics Controller:

```
def increment
 @music  = @Music.find(params[:music_id])
 @music.update_attribute(:rating, music.rating = music.rating+1)
 flash[:notice] = "Thanks for rating"
end
```

this is how i am calling it in the view:

```
<%= link_to "Like This Song", increase_rating_path(music.id) %>
```

and this is the route i have in place

```
match '/increment/:music_id', to: 'musics#increment', :as => 'increase_rating' , via: 'post'
```

this seems like a very simple thing to do but I cannot figure out why its not working,

any advice would be great thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First. Model class name start with capital character.

```
 @music = Music.find(params[:music_id])
```

Second. local variable 'music' dosen't exist in scope.
Use instance variable assigned above '@music' instead of 'music'

```
 @music.rating = @music.rating + 1
```

Third. You don't need to assign 'music.rating = music.rating + 1', [Reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute)

```
@model.update_attribute(:column, :value)
```

Just use value

```
@music.update_attribute(:rating, @music.rating + 1)
```

Finally.

```
def increment
   @music  = Music.find(params[:music_id])
   @music.update_attribute(:rating, @music.rating + 1)
   flash[:notice] = "Thanks for rating"
end
```

Comment: and check your request whether 'get' or 'post'. you assigned ':via => post'

Comment: Nice answer @Taekmin Kim

Answer (score 0):

you can use increment! method increase count. [increment!](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment!)

```
def increment
 @music  = Music.find(params[:music_id])
 @music.increment!(:rating, by = 1)
 flash[:notice] = "Thanks for rating"
end
```